# Wso identityserver 5.2.0 can't call federated oidc authenticator secured with client certificate

Tags: ssl, wso2, federated

I am trying to implement a federated oidc authenticator in Wso2 identityserver 5.2.0. After I succeeded configuring this connection, the federated authenticator implemented more strict security rules. Client do have to authenticate with a client certificate. I have imported the signing authority into the client trust store and the client certificate into the wso2carbon keystore. Running the code standalone with these keystore works fine. So I have no issue with the keystores.

But when I run the code in Wso2 with ssl debug I see the output:

```
    *** CertificateRequest
    Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
    Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA512withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x7), Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x9), Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0xa), Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0xb), Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x4), Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x5), Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x6), SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA512withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x3), SHA1withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x1), SHA1withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x3, signature:0x2), SHA1withDSA, SHA256withDSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), Unknown (hash:0x6, signature:0x2)
    Cert Authorities:
    <CN=TTP...>
    <OU=VeriSign...>
    <CN=TTP..>
    <CN=INSI...>
    http-nio-9443-exec-46, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
    *** ServerHelloDone
    Warning: no suitable certificate found - continuing without client 
    authentication
    *** Certificate chain
    <Empty>
    ***
```

The client certificate can not be found. In the standalone code I the client certificate found using the same keystores.

Is there some extra configuration needed in Wso2?

Comment: did you make sure that the 'clientAuth' attribute in the Connector tag is set to either “want” or "true" in <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml file?

Comment: yes clientAuth = want. But I think this property indicates that a client can send a client certificate to identity server. The issue I facing is, identity server itself must send a client certificate to a federated authenticator.